# Listview makes Issue in Jellybean Android

Tags: android, listview

In my app I am using Listview with 4 Textviews and 1 Checkbox. With the use of Base adapter class, I create my own adapter class to add list values in a Listview.

It is working fine in all android devices from 2.2 to 4.0 but in 4.2 bean for each touch on checkbox makes Unfortunately app closed Exception Alert.

Please tell me the solution and let me know if any other details required.

Comment: @Dhamodharan-I suggest you to make custom list-view. It is easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, It was happened one of the clients device. And I have check with my emulator, but can't get any issue in emulator.

Comment: I already used the custom listview.

Comment: @Dhamodharan this might not be an issue with listview, i suspect that your are invoking some library like **ksoap** on checkbox click??

Comment: Using the json, I will update the checkins in webservice. Does it cause any problem?